# Can github actions include postgresql with uuid support?

Tags: postgresql, uuid, github-actions

I have a working GitHub action which installs PostgreSQL 11. But now I use UUIDs and those are not supported.

I need to run `CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";` to install UUIDs but it is not clear how to do that with GitHub Actions.

I've thrashed and tried several other Docker images which have UUID support enabled but they are old user throw-always and do not support Actions.

My `Rust.yml` is below:

```
name: Rust

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        rust: [stable, beta]
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:11.6
        ports:
        - 5432:5432
        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5
    env:
      RUSTFLAGS: -D warnings
      CARGO_INCREMENTAL: 0
      RUN_SLOW_TESTS: 1
      RUSTUP_MAX_RETRIES: 10
      CARGO_NET_RETRY: 10
    steps:
      - uses: hecrj/setup-rust-action@v1
        with:
          rust-version: ${{ matrix.rust }}
          components: rustfmt
          targets: wasm32-unknown-unknown
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        if: matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest'
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libudev-dev zlib1g-dev alsa libasound2-dev
      - name: Build
        run: cargo build --verbose
      - name: Install Diesel CLI
        run: cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
      - name: Setup Diesel
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/nof1_time_series
        run: diesel setup
      - name: Run tests
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/nof1_time_series
        run: cargo test --verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to include the following `/migrations/00000000000010_install_uuid_feature/Up.sql` as an own migration early in the migration set and run as superuser `postgres`:

```
-- Install the UUID extension to this database
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

Other UUID tips if you are using Rust Diesel as your ORM:

1. Make sure to include the Diesel features you need:

```
[dependencies]
diesel = { version = "1.4", features = ["postgres", "chrono", "uuidv07", "serde_json"] }
uuid = {version = "0.8", features = ["serde", "v4"]}
chrono = { version = "0.4", features = ["serde"] }
```

2. Do not check formatting in the Github Action- the generated Diesel Schema will cause that to fail the build.
3. My updated Github Action for Rust Diesel with UUID support is below:

```
name: Rust

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ${{ matrix.os }}
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        os: [ubuntu-latest]
        rust: [stable, beta]
    services:
      postgres:
        image: postgres:11.6
        ports:
        - 5432:5432
        options: --health-cmd pg_isready --health-interval 10s --health-timeout 5s --health-retries 5
    env:
      RUSTFLAGS: -D warnings
      CARGO_INCREMENTAL: 0
      RUN_SLOW_TESTS: 1
      RUSTUP_MAX_RETRIES: 10
      CARGO_NET_RETRY: 10
    steps:
      - uses: hecrj/setup-rust-action@v1
        with:
          rust-version: ${{ matrix.rust }}
          components: rustfmt
          targets: wasm32-unknown-unknown
      - uses: actions/checkout@master
      - name: Install Dependencies
        if: matrix.os == 'ubuntu-latest'
        run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libudev-dev zlib1g-dev alsa libasound2-dev
      - name: Build
        run: cargo build --verbose
      - name: Install Diesel CLI
        run: cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres
      - name: Setup Diesel
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/timeseries
        run: diesel setup
      - name: Run tests
        env:
          DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:postgres@localhost/timeseries
        run: cargo test --verbose
```

4. Complete example [time-series-database](https://github.com/N-of-1/time-series-database/)